# Python Script to JSON as Geo-processing service

Tags: arcpy, json, geoprocessing-service, dictionary

I have been having some trouble with this script that I created. Ideally, I would like to query between to a layer file and feature class to find certain features in the class withing a certain distance from the layer file.

Then take certain attributes from those selections and store them in a python dictionary which will be converted into a JSON format and uploaded as a geoprocessing service.

I have excluded the remaining code because this bulk is what seems to be dis-functioning.

As a standalone script, it works fine and gives me the information intended. As a service -- here is the error received

[image]

```
import arcpy
import sys, os
import json  
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
segid = arcpy.GetParameter(0)                                                                                                                                  connection1 = r'Database Connections\DDOTLRS as LRSVIEWER.sde'
connection2 = r"Database Connections\Connection to DDOTGIS as DDOTEDITOR.sde"
supports = os.path.join(connection2, 'TOA.Supports') 
                                                                                           def getFeatureOIDsNearSeg(selectthesefeatures = None, segid = None , distance=150):
    '''  Function to spatially query for features within a certain distance of a street segment.
    user has option to provide distance '''                                                                                                                                                                                  streetsegs = os.path.join(connection1,'Ddotlrs.RH.LRSE_StreetSegment')                         streetsegs_lyr = "streetsegs_lyr"                                                                   selectthesefeatures_lyr = "selectthesefeatures_lyr"


try:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(streetsegs, streetsegs_lyr, "STREETSEGID = " + str(segid)) #only selecting this block street seg ID
except ValueError:
    print "Error.  Cannot find this StreetSeg ID.  Check ID or source (currently set to {0})".format(segid)

try:
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(in_layer=selectthesefeatures_lyr,
                                           overlap_type="WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",
                                           select_features=streetsegs_lyr,
                                           search_distance=str(distance) + " FEET",
                                           selection_type="NEW_SELECTION")
    #need to find out what was selected...
    selectthesefeatures_lyr_sel_desc = arcpy.Describe(selectthesefeatures_lyr)
    selectthesefeatures_lyr_sel_FIDS = selectthesefeatures_lyr_sel_desc.FIDset.split(";")
    selectthesefeatures_selected = ','.join(map(str, selectthesefeatures_lyr_sel_FIDS)) #capture all the IDs for the selected supports
    OIDs = "OBJECTID in ( " + selectthesefeatures_selected + ")"
    return OIDs
except ValueError:
    print "Error.  Problem selecting supports along this segment {0}.".format(segid)
return OIDs
```

Comment: Please add the error message you're getting.

Comment: So as a stand alone script, it works fine and gives me the information intended. As a service -- error received is posted above

Comment: Based on the error - take your .SDE file and copy it somewhere like `c:\temp`, then update this path in your code `connection1 = r'Database Connections\DDOTLRS as LRSVIEWER.sde'` to reflect that new location and republish.

Comment: Same situation/solution here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175407/arcpy-packageworkspace-doesnt-keep-reference-to-sde-enterprise-geodatabase